# Making floating button partially transparent android

Tags: android, android-layout

I've added floating action button to the app now want to make it partially transparent. I've already tried setting background with less opacity. Seems like nothing works. Is it possible to do so? I think it should be. Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible. [From the Android documentation, you can set the opacity from 0 to 1.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29)

> Sets the opacity of the view to a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means the
>   view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely
>   opaque.

Comment: Thanks this worked fine (:  `float a = (float) 0.5;
        fab.setAlpha(a);`